# Arrays: Splitting filenames

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So, I am still working on this javascript problem.  I am wanting to take a filename, say 
ABC1234_DEF456_7.pdf as a variable, and split it into

> Semester: ABC
>   Year:     2012
>   Program:  DEF
>   Course Number: 456
>   Section: 7
>   File Type: pdf

I can get them separated, but only so far.  Here is my code, and help would be great.

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var str = "ABC123_ABC123_1.jpg";
        var res = str.replace(/_/g, " ");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I believe the year should be `1234` not 2012...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
"ABC1234_DEF456_7.pdf".match(/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)_([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)_(\d+)\.(.+)/)
```

Output:

```
["ABC1234_DEF456_7.pdf", "ABC", "1234", "DEF", "456", "7", "pdf"]
```

Comment: That seperated it right up!  Thank you!  How do I use the <br> tag to put the answers on seperate lines?

Comment: @user3034841, mplungjan means this: `"ABC1234_DEF456_7.pdf ".match(/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)_([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)_(\d+)\.(.+)/).slice(1).join('<br>')`

Comment: Thank you so much gdoron!  You are awesome!